# Java - Filling a grid layout with JButtons based on indexes in an array

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, jbutton

Is there a way to create an array with indexes so that I can use a grid layout to quickly create Jbuttons in only these indexes that I need.  I'm making a game board for a project and I'm trying to do this as painlessly as possible and GUI is not my strongest feature.

```
// Set the height to the number of rows, length to number of columns
setLayout(new GridLayout(mineGrid.length, mineGrid[0].length);
  // For each row
  for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < mineGrid.length; rowIndex++) {
   // For each column
   for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < mineGrid[0].length; colIndex++) {
    // Add the button, because of GridLayout it starts @ the top row, goes across left to right, down a row, across left to right, etc.
    add(mineGrid[rowIndex][colIndex];
    }
   }
```

This code I had found was about a minesweeper game and actually puts mines in but I'm not sure this applies the same concept.
To make it a little more understandable what I mean is that for example I want to make a 25x25 grid layout and I don't want to make JButtons for indexes (5,2),(7,6),(24,25), is there anyway to exclude these buttons? Or would it just be easier to manually remove them.

*For my application of this process I will need more than 3 indexes excluded so if you choose to answer please think about it on a larger scale, around 25 or high indexes.*